# The proof of a function being factorable into the product of functions of two of it variables given that they are independent of each other.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

In [this](https://youtu.be/cy8r7WSuT1I?t=872s) video at 14:32, Grant says that if a there are two variables in a function and these functions are independent then the function can be factored into the product of functions of the individual variables.

What's the proof of this?

For eg:
$$ f(x, y) = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} $$
is a function where x and y are independent of each other. But is this factorable into the product $g(x)h(y)$? What's the general proof of this?

Comment: I won't watch a video to fill in the details. That function is not a product of the form you ask about. You have to work with the definition of "independence" in your context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the video, 3B1B is talking about independence in the statistical sense. We are looking for a function $f(x, y)$ that is a joint probability distribution of two random variables $X$ and $Y$, which by definition means that $f(x, y) = g(x)h(y)$ for some functions $g$ and $h$. This is analogous to independence in discrete probability, where you have $P(X = x, Y = y) = P(X = x)P(Y = y)$.